# iterate over IHTMLElementCollection

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, loops, ihtmldocument2

is there a way to iterate over IHTMLElementCollection?

such as

```
var
  e : IHTMLLinkElement;
elementCollection:IHTMLElementCollection;
begin
    for e in elementCollection do
      showmessage(e.caption);
end;
```

i know there is a property named _newEnum, however it is not supported in delphi as much as i could understand.

update:
apperently links are IHTMLElement and not IHTMLLinkElement

Comment: I read this as "irate over IHTMLElementCollection" and thought "It can't be that bad!"  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for I := 0 to Pred(elementCollection.length) do
begin
  e := elementCollection.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
  //...
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code to use _newEnum looks like this. If you're sure you've only got link elements items in the collection, you could change the `as IHTMLElement` part (and the elem value type) of the inner loop to `as IHTMLAnchorElement` (IHTMLLinkElement appears to be something entirely different)

```
uses MSHTML, ActiveX;

var
  collection:IHTMLElementCollection;
  enum:IEnumVariant;
  v:OleVariant;
  u:IUnknown;
  element:IHTMLElement;
begin
  //...
  enum:=collection._newEnum as IEnumVariant;
  while enum.Next(1,v,u)=S_OK do
   begin
    elem:=u as IHTMLElement;
    //...
   end;
```

Comment: +1 This could quite easily be wrapped up as a Delphi enumerator.

Comment: Perhaps it is? I've heard the most recent Delphi versions have a foreach statement that uses an enumeration interface if one is available, perhaps this includes IEnumVariant? (I can't check because I don't have the most recent Delphi version yet)